# How to choose a set of numbers such that sum of any combination of numbers in that set yields a unique result?

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, combinations

I don't remember whether it was VLC or Utorrent exactly but there was a settings page wherein you could choose:

Option A (3)
Option B (5)
Option C (7)

The way you would choose these options was by adding the corresponding numbers and typing it down. If you type 12 for example, it would know you have chosen B and C. Similarly 15 implies all three options.

I tried to make my own version of this by taking first 6 primes

A = 3
B = 5
C = 7
D = 11
E = 13
F = 15

But there was a discrepancy when the result was 18. It could either mean C + D or it could mean B + E.

How to choose a set of numbers such that sum of any combination of numbers in that set yields a unique result?

Comment: My initial guess was it had something to do with prime numbers so I choosed only primes

Comment: As joriki pointed out below, powers of two are usually used for this type of features. You could also use multiplication, where each factor is the corresponding prime if the option was selected, or 1 if not. This way, the product of all factors uniquely identifies the options which were selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to use powers of two. Then each summand corresponds to a set bit in the binary representation of the sum, so you can readily and uniquely reconstruct which summands were used from that binary representation.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about the binary system! Thanks :) I wonder if there is a general rule for finding such numbers...

Comment: @Macindows: More generally, you can use any positional numeral system instead of the binary one. To find more general sets, you can build them one by one, checking for each element you add whether it would create an ambiguity. I don't know of a more specific algorithm than that.